# test if exception was thrown - java

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, gradle, junit

I have the following code (the part that throws the exception is obviously part of a class but I only put the relevant lines).

```
if (found==null)
{
    log.warn("Got request from source IP - " + ip + " which is not in the env - not answering");
    throw new SourceHostUnknownException("This command is only supported from within the Environment");
}



@Test
public void testSecurityResult_whenRVERegex_assertexception()
{

    Throwable exception = Assertions.assertThrows(SourceHostUnknownException.class, () -> {
        SecurityResult result = secSvc.validateRequest(req);
    });
    String expectedMessage = "This command is only supported from within the Environment";
    String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();

    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedMessage,actualMessage);
}
```

My goal is to test if the exception was thrown, but when I'm trying to get the message from the exception, the value is null- meaning, the exception doesn't contain the message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify - is `exception` null or `actualMessage` null?  Did you try debugging, and step through the code?  Does `SourceHostUnknownException`'s constructor pass the message to the base class?

Comment: Thank you, your question guided me to the answer. I didn't handle the message in the constructor.

Comment: How is this Question related to Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Assertions.assertThatExceptionOfType(SourceHostUnknownException.class).isThrownBy(() -> {
        SecurityResult result = secSvc.validateRequest(req);
    }).withMessage("This command is only supported from within the Environment");
```

---

And if this does not work, check if the class `SourceHostUnknownException` is setting the constructor parameter correctly into super message field

for example, if you create custom exception class and you define constructor you need to pass the String message to super, as you are expecting **getMessage()** method to return you the error message.

```
public class SourceHostUnknownException extends Exception {

public SourceHostUnknownException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
}
```